# Windows 7 moves all program windows to single screen when reconnecting external screen(s)

Tags: windows-7, windows, display

I frequently disconnect my external displays from my laptop to take it with me (it's a workstation that natively supports driving two external displays).  Every time I come back and reconnect it, all of the running programs have been moved to the left-most display instead of where I left them.

I've seen other posts noting similar misbehavior with Windows 8.

Is it possible for Windows to actually remember the positions of its windows when disconnecting and connecting multiple displays?

Comment: I'm adding this comment because I really would like to know if there is something that can be done - maybe we are just plain stuck with this behavior? Sometimes simply sleeping my desktop PC causes windows to shift onto a single monitor. *sigh*

Comment: @DaveRook: I figured the implied question was obvious.  Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging the external monitor and then sing your laptop somewhere else would cause your PC to adjust to a new configuration. Hence coming back to the workstation is also a new configuration because you were just moments ago working on the same computer with no external monitors.

The PC is compensating dynamically. However you might be able to create a separate login; meaning create an identical user administrator account, but make sure to shutdown the workstation login before unplugging external monitors so the PC doesn't' compensate before saving current settings/configs.

Also you will have to share all required folders with this new login/admin account as well  -- make them visible via sharing any and all folders. I think that should do it.